# How to create a web based client for my program

Tags: java, php, html, vb.net

I need some help in how/where to start...
I have a program that is written in vb.net (i plan to convert it to Java), nothing fancy, it basically executes a number of bat files, opens specific folder, mainly command  line tasks.

I want to be able to control this program from a web browser, from a web page that simply mimics my program's gui with clickable buttons, so when i click a button on the browser, it executes the commands as if i were sitting in front of the PC using my program.

What i have gathered so far is that i need to use a webserver.
I was thinking of creating my own using Java Socket and ServerSocket...would this be the way to go?

thanks in advance

Comment: indirectly you want to develop a Web app that has same functionality as your Desktop app ? or you just want to run Desktop app from the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to expose the application functionality as a set of HTTP services, then you can create a web client (or mobile, in the future) for that application. If you require bidirectional communication. You can use websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Creating you own webserver will be a lot of work. Why don't you use an open-source Java server like Glassfish, Apache Tomcat or Jetty.

I'd recommend looking at something like JAX-RS to create a RESTful webservice. Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) that'll walk you through everything to get a basic REST service up and running from scratch.